# Not able to locate initial-status.gz. What might be the problem here?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, installed-programs

I am currently running **Ubuntu 16.04**, trying to salvage a list of packages installed but failed to find the `initial-status.gz` archive when I looked it up in `/var/log/installer/`.

What could possibly be the issue?

It's worth mentioning that I am new to this, so it'd be great if you could break it up as much as possible, in order for me to digest whatever it is.

Thank you. :)

Comment: I can't locate it either...

Comment: Try `sudo ls -lt --time-style=full-iso /var/log/installer/` as I've seen mine is the last thing created in that folder while installation. If  this is new installation, you may look for `ls -lt --time-style=full-iso /var/lib/dpkg/status*` . Ubiquity compresses `status` at the end of installation process. `status-old` is a backup copy.

Comment: What do you mean by  : _If this is new installation_ ? `ls -lt --time-style=full-iso /var/lib/dpkg/status*` gave me what I was looking for, though.  Thanks!

Comment: @Zanna, sure thank you for remind. GenghisKhan, I have copied my comment to an answer and updated it, with explanation why new installation. BTW, you can use `@username` to notify other user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've seen mine is the last thing created in that folder while installation. May be it didn't reach that step, see with:

```
sudo ls -lt --time-style=full-iso /var/log/installer/
```

If this is new installation , you may look for:

```
ls -lt --time-style=full-iso /var/lib/dpkg/status*
```

Ubiquity compresses `status` file at the end of installation process. `status-old` file is a backup copy.

Be aware that `/var/lib/dpkg/status` & `/var/lib/dpkg/status-old` reflect current and previous of the packages respectively and they are updated with each package installation/removal operation. In other hand, `/var/log/installer/initial-status.gz` is left as it was after Ubuntu (system) installation.That's why I said *"if your installation is new/fresh"*.

If it is relatively new (few days even with some package operations), you may filter out the packages you have added/removed by yourself from:

```
zcat /var/log/apt/history.log*
zcat /var/log/dpkg.log*
```

`dpkg.log` will more complete then `apt/history.log` because `apt` uses `dpkg` which does all package basic tasks.